# Drupal::request()->request->all() returns an empty array

Tags: 8

I have a custom controller that expects POST data. I had it working fine in 8.1.0 retrieving the data using `\Drupal::request()->request->all()` and `\Drupal::request()->request->get($myvar)`.

Now, without any changes in my custom module, `\Drupal::request()->request->all()` is returning an empty array, and `\Drupal::request()->request->get($myvar)` is returning `NULL`.

Between the time it was working and when the issue arose, my hosting service Pantheon updated their Drupal 8 version from 8.1.0 to 8.1.1 and then 8.1.2. I suspect something may have changed then that affected this.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**: Thanks for the comments, still not quite working...

Route YAML:

```
mymodule.foobar:
  path: '/foobar'
  options:
    _auth: [ 'basic_auth' ]
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\FooBarController::foobar'
    _title: 'foobar'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
/**
 * Class FooBarController.
 *
 * @package Drupal\mymodule\Controller
 */
class FooBarController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * Provides content for the /mymodule/foobar path.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
   *   The current request
   */
  public function foobar(Request $request) {
    $content = $request->getContent();
    $data = array();
    $data['a'] = $request->get('foo');
    $data['b'] = $request->request->get('foo');
    $data['c'] = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->request->get('foo');
    $data['e'] = $request->request->all();
    $data['f'] = $content;

    $request = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest();
    $content = $request->getContent();
    $data['g'] = $request->get('foo');
    $data['h'] = $request->request->get('foo');
    $data['j'] = $request->request->all();
    $data['k'] = $content;

    return new JsonResponse((object) $data);
  }
}
```

Postman Request:
[image]

Note: This was working before with this exact code, correctly using basic HTTP authentication. There have been no changes other than these variations to my controller, and core updates.

Any more ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the routing yml as well, and also the url with query you type in the browser? (eg //localhost/foo?foo="hello")

Comment: @ssibal good point. Added.

Comment: Can you var_dump please the $_REQUEST variable?

Comment: Aha, both $_REQUEST and $GLOBALS['_REQUEST'] are empty arrays. I've openned a ticket with my host to see if there is perhaps some PHP server configuration issue here...

Comment: I'm having the same issue except I only see data when using form-urlencoded which corrupts the posted data. The request parameters are always empty when I use json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get $\_POST and $\_GET parameters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207044/how-to-get-post-and-get-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the request parameters were always empty. I think it could be due to using it in a controller rather than a REST endpoint but I'm not sure.

The following line of code worked for me:

```
$request->getContent();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$request = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->query->all();
```

**Sidenote:** Using a Controller you shouldn't use "\Drupal::..." static request call. Instead, you always have in your controller's enter point function a "Request $request" object as a last argument.

Comment: "query" is for GET parameters, the question asked about POST parameters.