# How to get $_POST and $_GET parameters

Tags: 8, page-controller

I call a route via AJAX and pass data to it. In a controller, I want to get `$_POST['var']`, but it does seem to work on Drupal 8.

How I can get values contained in `$_POST` from a controller?

Comment: $_POST still exists, you just shoudn't use it directly. If $_POST is empty, then the request object will also be empty and your error happens earlier. Often, this is for example because mod_rewrite is not enabled/configured correctly and the page is redirect through the not found directive, which drops post data.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

From the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2150267):

```
$name = $_POST['name']; // form param
```

becomes

```
$name = \Drupal::request()->request->get('name'); // form param
```

Incidentally, for `GET` vars, you would use:

```
$query = \Drupal::request()->query->get('name');
```

Comment: thanks, and do you know how can I get  all items? I mean $_POST completely not one item.

Comment: I haven't checked, but knowing Symfony I'd assume: `\Drupal::request()->request->all()`

Comment: Thanks, this is true answer to my question although I didn't get  expected result ( maybe there is a problem in another place ,I ask it in another question.

Comment: I can confirm that you can use \Drupal::request()->query->all() to get all $_GET variables.

Comment: Request should be like this $name = \Drupal::request()->get('name'); // form param

Answer (score 44):

In a controller get the request with a type-hinted argument `Request $request`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ExampleController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Controller to return a POST or a GET parameter.
   */
  public function action(Request $request) {

    // get your POST parameter
    $foo = $request->request->get('foo');

    // or get your GET parameter
    $foo = $request->query->get('foo');

    // POST requests are not cached, but for GET you need a cache context
    return [
      '#plain_text' => $foo,
      '#cache' => ['contexts' => ['url.query_args:foo']],
    ];
  }

}
```

More info https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/using-parameters-in-routes

Use #plain_text to escape the input data for HTML output. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2559263

Answer (score 23):

Inject the `RequestStack` into your controller.

The current request contains the `query` attribute that in turn contains the GET parameters. `request` contains the POST parameters.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * An example controller.
 */
class ExampleController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  private $requestStack;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $request_stack
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack) {
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('request_stack')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function action() {
    // Get your GET parameter here.
    $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query->get('foo');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `Content-Type: application/json` please use :

```
$post_data = json_decode( $this->request->getContent(),TRUE);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check the Request object like

```
\Drupal::request()->getMethod();
```

it will returns GET or POST or whatever. If you are working inside an object, remember to DI the Request service.

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me but I found this that did:

```
$request->getContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for accessing URL parameters and passing them to a template.
I am assuming you have already created your module and required files and that */test?fn=admin* is the path your module is using.

In Your .module file implement `hook_theme()` and define variables and template name. (Make sure you replace *_* with *-* when creating the template file.)

```php
function my_module_theme () {   
  return [
    'your_template_name' => [
      'variables' => [
        'first_name'    => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Now create your controller and put the following code in it.

```php
 namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;
 
 use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

 class MyModule extends ControllerBase {
 
   public function content(Request $request) {
     return [
       '#theme' => 'my_template',
       '#first_name' => $request->query->get('fn'), //This is because the parameters are in $_GET, if you are accessing from $_POST then use "request" instead "query"
     ];
   }

 }
```

In template file, which should be *my-template.html.twig*, you can access this parameter as `<h3>First Name: {{ first_name }}</h3>`.