# How to get form values in URL as keys of an array

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom form with min and max price value:

```
    $form['price']['min'] = [
      '#type'          => 'hidden',
      '#default_value' => isset($_GET['price']['min']) ? $_GET['price']['min'] : '',
      '#attributes'    => ['id' => 'price-min'],
    ];

    $form['price']['max'] = [
     '#type'          => 'hidden',
     '#default_value' => isset($_GET['price']['max']) ? $_GET['price']['max'] : '',
     '#attributes'    => ['id' => 'price-max'],
    ];
```

and I would like the URL after the form is submitted to look like this:

```
/search?price%5Bmin%5D=5000&price%5Bmax%5D=10000
```

but actually it's coming out like this:

```
/search?min=5000&max=10000
```

How can I get the form values to appear in the URL in the required format?

Comment: Apart from your 'question' missing some details and the actual question, you should not use `$_GET` in your form, but get the parameters from the request object.

Comment: Ok Mario like this: '#default_value' => $form_state->getValue('price[min]'); ?

Comment: This makes no sense. As soon as you have a form state with a valid value (after a submission of this form), it will be the actual value of this field anyway. If you like to initialize the default values from the request URL, you'd have to use the request object. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207044/how-to-get-post-and-get-parameters

Comment: There was a point to this question, which is addressed in my answer, but it does need editing for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
$form['price']['#tree'] = TRUE;
```

This tells the form builder you want to nest field names. Otherwise it will just use the most immediate element keys for the field names, as you have found.

This is actually useful behaviour most of the time, as it means you can group fields in containers such as fieldsets without affecting their name attributes.