# How can I retrieve information about the current request's URL?

Tags: hooks

I need help finding a way to get the current request URL in a controller and, based on that, change the webform name in the controller.

My code:

```
'#url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.webform.canonical',['webform' => 'form1'])
```

In this line of code, how can I switch between `form1` or `form2` based on whether the request URL contains a particular path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URL info is available from the `request_stack` service. In procedural code getting the URL looks like this:

```
$url = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
```

There's also a helper to get query parameters if you need them, e.g.

```
if (!empty(\Drupal::request()->query->get('foo'))) {
  
}
```

In your case you should [inject the `request_stack` service into your controller](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8), and get the request object from its `getCurrentRequest()` method (rather than getting it from `\Drupal::request()` directly).

Answer (score 4):

> I need help finding a way to get the current request URL in a
> controller

In a controller get the request with a type-hinted argument `Request $request`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

class ExampleController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Controller to return a link to a webform.
   */
  public function action(Request $request) {

    // calculate $webform with $request->getPathInfo()

    return [
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => 'Foo',
      '#url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.webform.canonical', ['webform' => $webform]),
      '#cache' => ['contexts' => ['url.path']],
    ];
  }

}
```

You can get other information from the request, but then you need to adjust the cache context(s). See for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/245597/47547

Comment: You don't need to inject it? 

Comment: No, this is the most basic usage of a controller receiving a request and returning a response.